# Space complexity of function

Tags: javascript, big-o, complexity-theory, space

I'm new to working out space complexity and am stuck working out the following function

```js
const isUnique = string => {
  if (string.length > 128) {
    return false
  }

  let seen = new Set()

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (seen.has(string[i])) {
      return false
    }
    seen.add(string[i])
  }

  return true
}
```

Would it be O(n) as the set will grow in proportion to the size of the string? Or O(1) as it is a singe set no matter how large it gets and would never exceed 128 in length.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The Set instance has to store its contents somewhere, right? It's not magic. Now, the point about the overall process being limited to 128 characters might be an argument for it being considered O(1), though with that small a number it doesn't make any real difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's constant because there's a maximum size that the set might have, regardless how large your input gets.

In fact, it would even still be constant if the `string.length <= 128` restriction wasn't there, as long as the function expects a *string* and not an array of arbitrary items, as a string is characterised by being comprised of UTF-16 characters of which there is only a limited number - the set can never grow beyond the size of the alphabet, regardless how long the input is.